# Error when using npm start for a react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command-prompt, npm-start

I created a react app folder using "create-react-app" it worked well and when I tried "npm start" to is throwing errors. I have uninstalled and reinstalled, I tried setting path in the environment variables. Whatever I try it the same error over and over again.

[image: click here for image of the error shown]

The Error Message

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\sreem\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]

2 info using npm@6.14.5

3 info using node@v14.3.0

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info lifecycle movie@0.1.0~prestart: movie@0.1.0

6 info lifecycle movie@0.1.0~start: movie@0.1.0

7 verbose lifecycle movie@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle movie@0.1.0~start: PATH: 
C:\Users\sreem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\sreem\Desktop\movie\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin;;C:\Users\sreem\Documents\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\sreem\AppData\Roaming\npm

9 verbose lifecycle movie@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\sreem\Desktop\movie

10 silly lifecycle movie@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]

11 silly lifecycle movie@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle movie@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script

13 verbose stack Error: movie@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\sreem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sreem\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)

14 verbose pkgid movie@0.1.0

15 verbose cwd C:\Users\sreem\Desktop\movie

16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362

17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\sreem\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"

18 verbose node v14.3.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5

20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1

22 error movie@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the movie@0.1.0 start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: create-react-app is installed?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. @Rebai Ahmed